# API Connection String Not Working After Deploying to Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, api, swagger

First, I am well aware this may be a duplicate. I have looked but have not yet found a solution. If you can point me to one, I will gladly accept it!

I've built an API in VS 2019 using Core 5.0. This is the entire appsettings.json file:

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Server=...."
    }
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Works perfectly in localhost. But when I publish to Azure, all the results come back:

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

SOME articles I have read say that the App Service will use the `appsettings.json` file that comes with the app. Others say you need to add them manually in Azure Portal. I have tried adding the connection string manually, in multiple ways:

[image]

But I still get the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think `ConnectionStrings` should be a top-level-configuration, not a property of `AppSettings`? at least when using [GetConnectionString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationextensions.getconnectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) - i've never seen it as a property of AppSettings before.

Comment: See the second half of the image. I tried it as both. But either way, I would prefer the app to use the appsettings.json file!

Comment: it still belongs in the appsettings.json file. but `ConnectionStrings` should _not_ be a child-element of `AppSettings`, but on the _same_ level as it. also: it would be helpful to include the code where you access the setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the ConnectionStrings out of AppSettings to a higher level as below, also make sure you are mentioning the same in the portal

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "server=v6.com;database=tsde;uid=sa;pwd=234@123."
  },
```

Comment: ok I will try that. For the other settings in the appsettins.json file, do I also need to add them manually?

Comment: Not necessary, once you have that in appsettings.json it should be automatically taken, if not try to add manually and see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Ok, making some progress! Now I get: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

Comment: I confirmed that the value I put in the configuration connection string is correct. And it works in localhost.

Comment: The API isn't working yet, but your answer got me past the error I posted about. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I found something which may be useful on https://learn.microsoft.com: [Configure apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#:%7E:text=of%20setting%20names.-,Configure%20connection%20strings,in%20in%20Web.)

> For ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core developers, setting app settings in App
> Service are like setting them in  in Web.config or
> appsettings.json, but the values in App Service override the ones in
> Web.config or appsettings.json. You can keep development settings (for
> example, local MySQL password) in Web.config or appsettings.json and
> production secrets (for example, Azure MySQL database password) safely
> in App Service. The same code uses your development settings when you
> debug locally, and it uses your production secrets when deployed to
> Azure

Comment: this is not an answer. It's just a link.

Comment: This document shown what are you prefer in configure your App config